# access the public sub of an open instance

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a program made in .net which at the beginning has a system of tabs that open through the main menu, my problem is that now I need open a new tab from another place outside the main menu and I am not being able to do it, that is to say to explain myself a little better I have two forms, `Form1` and `Form2` (`Form2` is inside `Form1`)

In the first form I have the following code

```vb
Public Sub tabs(name As String)

    tabcontrol1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    gridinicio.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    Flyout.IsOpen = False
    Dim tabitem As New TabItem()
    tabitem.Header = name
    tabcontrol1.Items.Add(tabitem)

    tabitem.Content = _form
    tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex = tabcontrol1.Items.Count - 1

    Flyout_ClosingFinished(Nothing, Nothing)

End Sub
```

Inside `Form1` I can call it without problems, but being in `Form2` I don't know how to access `Public Sub tabs(name As String)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "`Form2` is inside `Form1`"? A `Form` is a top-level Window, they cannot be nested (unless you're using MDI windows?)

Comment: What is `_form`?

Comment: Form2 needs a reference to the **instance** of Form1 then it's simply form1.tabs() as per exactly how you are doing it within in Form1

Comment: Because VB supports default instances of forms and, assuming that `Form1` is your startup form, it is the default instance of its type, you can simply call `Form1.tabs` anywhere in the project. Of course, `tabs` is an absolutely terrible name for that method.

Comment: That said, using default instance is dodgy and the proper way to do this would be to have this other form raise an event that `Form1` attaches a handler to when it is created. The other form raises the event and `Form1` calls its own `tabs` method. I suggest that you read all three parts of [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html).